# How to use guava-18.0.jar in Liferay 5.2.3

Tags: java, liferay, guava, portlet, portal

I am developing my first portlet in Liferay 5.2.3, I am very new to this area.
Today I wanted to use "*guava-18.0.jar*" to benefit from "*Lists.revers()*" method, I put the jar file in the lib folder of my portlet. It gives me this error :

```
15:55:49,905 ERROR [[fozhan]:711] Servlet.service() for servlet fozhan threw exception
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1876)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1232)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at com.sample.jsp.portlet.JSPPortlet.processAction(JSPPortlet.java:95)
        at com.sun.portal.portletcontainer.appengine.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:100)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:618)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:664)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:359)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:604)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:428)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:195)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:157)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:608)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:399)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:143)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:140)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:282)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:425)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:257)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.opensso.OpenSSOFilter.processFilter(OpenSSOFilter.java:73)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:193)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.doFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocalcache.ThreadLocalCacheFilter.processFilter(ThreadLocalCacheFilter.java:55)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:154)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
15:55:49,986 ERROR [jsp:165] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1876)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1232)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at com.sample.jsp.portlet.JSPPortlet.processAction(JSPPortlet.java:95)
        at com.sun.portal.portletcontainer.appengine.filter.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:98)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:100)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:618)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:664)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:359)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can definitely use this :

```
Collections.reverse(list.clone());
```

Comment: Note that this does a lot more work than `Lists.reverse` (copying and then moving all the elements vs. just creating a view) and that it doesn't quite work as written since you need to assign the list copy to a variable first.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by the version of your Liferay. Guava Release 10.0 was released on September 28, 2011 which is probably after liferay 5.2.3